# Normalizing tables for a social networking type website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I am trying to build a website that it will harvest user's info and store them into a table. Lets name the table **user_details**. It will have the columns listed below:

id,country,city,name,surname,birthday,gender,email,password,phone_number,search_phone_number

id = 1,2,3,4.. INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY
phone_number= its unique but only in the same country. Maybe a person from UK will have the same phone_number with a person from Spain but not in UK. In other words its country-related. To make it unique the search_phone_number will be consisted of country+phone_number, ex: SPAIN394221234.

Users are going to search for other users using their unique search_phone_number.

Is there a need to try and normalize this table?

Also in the same website, i have built a simple PM system, and a gallery (showing the pictures the user uploaded). So i have 2 tables:
1)**message** table (sender, reiceiver,message,....)
2)**photos** table (directory, filename, ...)

Again, is there a need to normalize the message and photos tables?

I am a little bit confused, because in some occasions normalization is a must, but in some other its not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, if someone inserts a genuine number that isn't theirs, the real owner can't then insert it?

Comment: what about two+ users in a house sharing a phone number. "Oops"... DB tables should ALWAYS be normalized, unless you have an overwhelming performance issue where JOINing queries wouldn't be an option.

Comment: No. Its going to search the existing table and see if that Number is already registered. If yes, it will not accept it. To be honest its something i am thinking how to handle. My concern is about the database structure. I need to build something well-designed from the start.

Comment: Some people say that sometimes its better not to normalize your database. I quote "If you’ve ever tried doing a five-table join, you know that it works in principle, but its painstakingly slow in practice.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - create a new country table like ...

```
create table country (id int auto_incremenet primary key, country varchar(100));
```

2 - create a new city table like ...

```
create city (id int auto_increment primary key , city varchar(100), fk_country_id int);
```

fk_country_id will have the id of the country that city is located in

3 - in your table mentioned above, remove the country and city columns and add only fk_city_id column. fk_city_id will have the id of the city that person is located in

4 - create table for phones like

```
create table user_phones(id int auto_increment primary key, fk_country_id int, phone_number varchar(15)) ;
```

5 - add unique index to that table like so ..

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_country_phone ON user_phones(fk_country_id, phone_number);
```

remove phone number and search_phone_number from your table and add fk_user_phones_id column to your table.. it will have the id value of relevant row from user_phones table

6 - when user is doing a search, filter by country id and and the phone number

Comment: Supposed i am not using the normalization you suggested(which i am going to implement to to see how it works) what are the disadvantages when comparing to the table i described (a table having all details of the user)?

Comment: Your search_phone_number field will cause performance issues when it is too large.  Because assume you will have hundreds of thousands or millions of phone numbers from Spain that starts with Spain...  Even when indexed  db will not make efficient use of index because it will have to scan all rows starting with Spain until it finds the first number match.  Your column values should try to be as distinct as possible starting from beginning, so avoid using same prefixes in column  data

Comment: When I was working on millions of rows of voter data, we had a column that was prefixed by voter precinct (some precincts had millions of voters). I tracked down the issue to that prefix. Save yourself headache. Also, always start normalized and properly indexed on joining / searchable columns and only de normalize when you have performance issues later on. Databases are designed go perform heavy set operations (joins etc) efficiently. Don't be afraid to use them!

Comment: If the repeating value is a value that will never be used as search field (ex birthday) do i need to remove  it into a separate table as well?

Comment: No, you don't in this case

Comment: Just a question: What if I use the mysqli_result_id() function. This way if I create 3 tables (ex. user_details , location, credentials), by assigning the same ID (extract it using mysqli_insert_id after the first mysqli_query)to all tables I will be able to call info from any table I want, just by referring to that ID (AUTO_INCREMENT). This way all data in all tables where ID=1 will be considering the same user. Is this a solution?

Comment: No, it is not. You would have to repeat the same row again and again for each user (for example if 3 people are located in Nicosia, Cyprus, you would have 3 rows with that data for each user. That is against normalization! Just do as I suggested. When two or more users are from same city (Nicosia, Cyprus) for example, you can put id from city table for that city into fk_city_id column in the user_phones table. This way you will have only one row in the city table for Nicosia, Cyprus and more users can belong to it.  Please read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: At the analysis you wrote on my example, if I wanted to insert the address of the user, would I add this column on the user_details table or the city table? Or if I wanted to add more info about country (ex. population) or in add area_code column in user_phones table. I have read about normalization, but to be honest I am confused. Our goal is not to repeat data on the same column, but what if in the user_details table we have 2 users that have the same name or surname or birthday? Isnt this against normal form 2?

Comment: Also, if i get it right, the data for the tables country and city must be added by me and just use these tables to access user_phones table using the input from the user?

Comment: Yes, you first need to populate(fill) the country table. After you do that, each country will have an id. Then, you will populate the city table, in the fk_country_id field, you will put the country ids from country table. Then, you will populate the user_phones table and will put the id from city table in the fk_city_id field. Now, when you wanted to get city a user belongs, you join the user_phones, city, country tables like this: select userp.*, city.*, country.* from user_phones as userp inner join city on city.id = userp.fk_city_id inner join country on country.id=city.fk_country_id

Comment: You need to learn how to join tables. Learn here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html What you are asking is very basic. Please study joins and help yourself get better.

Comment: Yes, joining tables is easy. What was hard for me to understand was how to normalize the initial table. Once normalized, will it be efficient to add the address column to city table? Or area code on user_phone table? Thanks by the way.

Comment: This is tiring me. Please improve your knowledge on databases in general. Here is a good resource to start on normalization. http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php  All the best